# How can I reward a user who helped me in the comments?

Tags: support

The user "UnholySheep" helped me in the comments by suggesting an out of bounds index, however since it's in the comments upvoting doesn't do anything. Can I reward him/her somehow? Is there a way to send reputation to a user? ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41572683/strange-output-when-printing-string-c))

Comment: Whew! **First** thing to do is *restore your question*! As it is, it's no longer a question: "Here's the WORKING code"! You should leave the 'wrong' version there, you can always post the solution as a separate answer.

Comment: @RadLexus I did! I posted an answer, but I cannot accept it right away, two days have to pass (that's a rule). I no longer have the wrong version.

Comment: The wording of the text suggests there is no problem in the code in there. All such information should not be there in the question. Please make sure it remains a real, standalone, question.

Comment: If the user wanted to get reputation for helping you, they would have posted an answer.

Comment: Granted, if the question needed a lot of clarification in the comments, it wouldn't have been a good idea to answer it before that clarification was accomplished. Sometimes the question gets answered during the clarification. It's not a big deal. People wouldn't help if they didn't want to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't. Or, well, maybe you *can* but you *should* not.

Here is why.

Suppose you click the name of this user and check out his **Questions and Answers**. Click a random one and upvote it.

That is not fair. If you don't know what the question or answer is about, you cannot decide whether it's a good one or not. What if you accidentally upvote a very bad answer, making others - with as much experience as you - think it's actually a *good* answer?

Okay, so find a answer of which you *can* appreciate its correctness and upvote *that*.

Still not fair. There may be other answers which are just as good or better, but you are deliberately picking one based on the poster's name.

So, you pick a question where this OP is the only answerer and upvote *that*.

Still not fair. Even then, you are not voting for the *correctness* of that answer!

In conclusion, don't vote "for" a user in any way, vote for contents only.

---

What you could have done: invite the commenter to post the comment *as a proper answer*. There are lots of benefits attached to that. Not only can the commenter add more detail to it, but also others can more easily comment on it as well, and vote it up *or* down (!), which is not possible with comments.

In addition, comments are primarily meant for asking clarifications (a "rule" that is often enthousiastically broken by everyone, including me), and it's always possible they can get deleted without any notification.

Comment: I couldn't have invited them to post it because it was just an suggestion, not an answer, thanks anyways.

Comment: @theo2003: usually such a suggestion is done because the commenter has an idea of what's *actually* wrong. If I'm fishing for a solution with a comment, I can usually expand that into a full answer.

Comment: I like the nuance in this answer. Everybody does that from time to time. But this isn't how the site should work.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing you should do is upvote their comment.

Comments which answer the question are pretty common, but are discouraged because we would prefer people to post answers instead of leaving answers in the comments. Users also don't expect to receive a reward for helping via a comment, so there is no obligation to do so. Let reputation be earned naturally, not artificially.

If the user doesn't post an answer, it's fine for you to post an answer which explains the problem and solution, and then credits the user (as you've done).

Comment: it's also appreciated to post as community wiki, which doesn't leave the impression you're making rep on the back of the commenter.