# Why can comments only have negative flags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

On my recent question [Excel forcing Text NumberFormat on a cell with Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52547331/2675154), @chillin commented and actually supplied the answer for that question in his comment.  I tried to flag the comment as the answer, but was surprised that I could only select negative comments.  I think it must occur quiet often that an answer is given in a comment, so there should be a mechanism to flag a comment as an answer (possibly through automatic conversion into an answer), otherwise it results in two undesirable consequences. (1) Potentially the question is left never answered. (2) The commenter that supplied the answer in a comment is never credited.

The answers for: [How can I reward an user who helped me in the comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341258/how-can-i-reward-an-user-who-helped-me-in-the-comments) answers some of the questions, however I would still like to put up for discussion the proposal of being able to flag a comment as an answer, possibly through automatic conversion into an answer or automatic request to the commenter to post as answer.  I think the manual processes suggested in the answers to the cited questions are cumbersome and my suggestions would improve usability.

Comment: Your edit just makes your question a duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258343/add-an-option-to-promote-comment-to-answer someone with a gold discussion badge can add that in to the duplicate list.

Comment: Ok I accept that, still think there is room for improvement in the system here.

Answer (score 9):

Answers are for answers, comments are not. Comments are transient and can be deleted anytime, they are not for storing useful information. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). You can upvote a comment, but that's it. There is no other way of marking a comment as useful.

What you can do if your problem received an answer in a comment:

- Ask the commenter to turn this into an answer themself
- If they do not respond / don't care, you can turn the comment(s) into an answer yourself (if you feel like you shouldn't receive reputation for their contribution, you can mark the answer as *community wiki* (see check mark in the lower right corner of the answer text field), so you'll get no reputation, but the info will be stored).