# How do I reward someone that answered my question, if he answered it indirectly

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, reputation, bounty, accepted-answer

I have asked a question, that I closed as a duplicate, one of those answers helped me a lot. And I don't think there should be to many "almost the same" questions out there.

How do I show my appreciation?

---

I asked this question: [How can I read a single char from stdin without invoking bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53893581/10822366)
And "fess ." provided the perfect answer.

I know there is a bounty-system, can I somehow award a bounty to someone on the "original" of the "duplicate"?

I should at least award the 35 (10 upvoted and 25 accepted) reputation points, even if it comes out of my own reputation pocket (as soon as I can afford it).

An other solution:

I ask him to duplicate his answer to my question. That would help those that had the same question more than them having to click the duplicate link, and then sorting out the one that also applies to other shells than ksh. Would that be the right way?

What is the right thing to do?

Comment: Related: [How can I reward a user who helped me in the comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341258/2564301).

Comment: @usr2564301 not the exact same but definitely strongly related. sadly the answer to that question is "don't do it, because there is no proper way" (I summarized)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> How do I show my appreciation?

This is Stack Overflow, you have several solutions; some are encouraged, others frown upon.

#### Bounty

Once you earn [enough reputation points (75)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), you can set a bounty (50 or more) on the duplicate question. Rewarding an existing answer is one of the usual use case.
[image: start a bounty...]
[image: ...to reward an existing answer]

24h after that, you can manually award your bounty to fess' answer:
[image: award a bounty]

It will surely show your appreciation; further more, it will show to other readers that this answer is somewhat special.

#### Upvote

Upvoting an answer provides 10 reputation points to its author. This is the common way to show appreciation.

#### Comment the answer with a "thank you"

This is frowned upon since you do not provide additional information. Please don't unless you have an improvement suggestion to make.

#### Duplicate fess' answer into your question

We don't like duplicates, please don't.

#### Upvote several answers of fess

This is not only discouraged, it is a case of [serial voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) and is disallowed on the stack exchange network.

> When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them. This could happen for a variety of reasons, such as a user finding a user's great answer and visiting all of their posts to upvote them, or a user getting into an argument with another user and downvoting their posts indiscriminately in revenge. No matter the cause, this sort of systematic targeted voting is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.

Comment: Thank you (others can now frown upon this comment)

Comment: also frowned upon: upvote several unrelated answers of the answerer. This is considered as serial upvoting.

Comment: WRT commenting "thank you", I find a huge difference between "thank you" and "I can't thank you enough for your explanation, I have been struggling with this for a while and you've cleared everything up. All I can award you is an upvote but know you've helped me greatly". Both are noise and discouraged, but one shows a lot more appreciation. You can always come back and delete your comment in say 24 or 48h.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre tk, added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Bounty would be a good way to do this, but since you don't have enough reputation to o a bounty yet, you can't, you need 75 reputation to set a bounty, so in this case, best thing is only to up-vote him.</del>

<del>Up-vote will work now, after you get 75 reputation, you'll get privilege to set bounties.</del>

<del>you have to wait until 75 rep, so you can set a bounty, up-vote won't make much appreciation, since it is community wiki post, and the votes don't count for community wiki posts.</del>

fess.'s answer is not community wiki now, so can do anything you want.

**EDIT:**

fess.'s answer is not community wiki, so you can up-vote it, and he'll get rep from from as usual, and also can set bounty as usual, so everything will be as normal as usual, bounty would be actually a good hit, show your appreciation.

Comment: So i would set a bounty to the original question (not my duplicate) and then award it to his answer? does that work if it is already a community wiki? Or have I missed some feature that can award a bounty to a user without there being a question/answer?

Comment: @Sam 1. it works with Community Wiki post, 2. No, you can't.

Comment: @U9-Forward: could you rephrase "won't make any sense" (cause it did make sense for me to upvote a good answer) to something like "won't provide the intended benefit/reputation".

Comment: @Sam I say that because you won't get any voting reputation from community wiki posts, so it won't add 10 reputation do him.

Comment: I know that, still I am always thinking about others reading it, and they hardly ever read all the comments, maybe not even the question. But If you insist that "makes no sense" is the right way to phrase it, who am I to argue.

Comment: @Sam Edited mine.

Comment: @U9-Forward thx, might be just me, but I cold not accept an answer that told me my "reputationless" upvote made no sence :)

Comment: @Sam Really? :-)

Comment: fess' answer [is not a community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30022297/5470596)

Comment: @all how stupid of me, there was just a "automatic" edit, which registers as user "Community" and has the same icon, and because I do not have enough reputation to contribute to a wiki, the "edit button taskbar" also looks the same.

Comment: @YSC: when you do, keep my original question in mind, even the posibility to dublicate the answer. "fess ." is still active. I am removing the wiki part from my question.

Comment: @Sam Okay, good, realized what's the thing at the end.

Comment: @YSC and U9-Forward: I think the real answer is: "ask a good meta question, which brings so much attention to his answer, that it gets upvoted by 3 people". but still: I should have the 75 rep soon enough to do what I intended anyway: use the bounty system,

Comment: @Sam This is known as the meta effect. Beware, it's double-edged.